# rake error with rails 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I just upgraded to Linux Mint 14 and to Rails 3.2.9 from 3.2.8.  Now I'm getting this error when I run `rake db:create`

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `values_at' for "MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.":String
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

my Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: What happended to your original database? Did you delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you forgot to update some dependencies?
Try to run:

```
$ bundle outdated
```

and check if you need to update other gems....